# What is heavy tailed distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to understand the heavy tailed distribution. I took help of Internet but I'm not able to comprehend mathematical definition of heavy tailed distribution. Can anyone explain me the Heavy-tailed distribution in layman terms with some example.

Comment: A real random variable $X$ is [*heavy-tailed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution#Definition_of_heavy-tailed_distribution) if the mean of $e^{tX}$ is infinite for all $t>0$. Is there a part of that that's especially unclear?

Comment: Yes, can you give me intuition for the same

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a continuous distribution. Its tails are the values below $\underline x$ or above $\bar x$. If a distribution is heavy tailed, the probabilities $P(x<\underline x)$ or $P(x>\bar x)$ are large, i.e., larger than those of the exponential distribution